# Não consigo dar push no git

Tags: git, github

[image: Erro ao dar push no git!]

Galera estou com esse probleminha no git quando dou o push apresenta esse erro. Criei o repositório online acessei a pasta do projeto local pela cli do git Executei os comandos: (git, init, status. add ., commit...) fiz tudo no padrão mas mesmo assim o erro permanece

Comment: Fez o gitpull? A mensagem diz que o repositório que você está tentando fazer commit está mais a frente do seu local..

Comment: Provavelmente um readme, algo que vc não criou local...

Comment: Quando vc fizer o gitpull ele vai atualizar o local com o remoto, se houver conflito vai ter o famoso merge, se tudo der certo é um merge automático, senão vc vai ter que resolver. Depois disso vc vai poder fazer seu push.

Comment: Vc já rodou o comando e o git está informando  "remote origin already exist" ou seja origem remota já existe... já executou uma vez....  olhe e vê se ja tem o comando aplicado .....   git remote -v

Answer (score 0):

O que aconteceu foi que vc trocou a ordem dos comandos do git, você colocou "git branch - M main" antes do "git remote add origin ..." e isso desatualizou seu repositório local.

Faz esse comando pra forçar a substituição da branch remota pelo código que vc tem no repositório local:

```
git push -f origin main
```